# How to disable anchor link form Document Lib in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I want to disable create new document anchor option from my Document Lib.

Comment: you need to disable new document or hide it ? what do you need specifically ?

Comment: I want to disable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS in Script Editor to hide to + Document

```
 <style>
    #idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ2 {
    display: none ! important;
    }
    </style>
```

If you need to hide + Document and drag and drop

```
<style>
    #Hero-WPQ2 {
    display: none ! important;
    }
    </style>
```

For more details check [Hide + new document and drag files option in Document Library in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/15/hide-disable-new-doc-drag-drop-files-document-library-sharepoint-2013/#more-14419)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps :

1. GoTo All items page of your document library
2. Append "**?toolpaneview=2**"  and hit the url (this will open your page in edit mode) or go to settings and click on edit page.
3. Edit Web Part
4. Set ToolBar type to "No Toolbar"

[image]

5. Apply
6. Done

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thank you Rohit for reply But  I need drag and drop available only and  + new need to disable or hide.